# Decimal to JSON

Tags: python, django

I'm pulling a sum from a DB which is a decimal value.
I'm trying to use that value in a JSON result

```
json.dumps( { 'sum': amount } ) #where amount is my Decimal
```

Django can't serialize the `Decimal`.
I can convert it to a string, but I'd like a numeric type within the JSON.
If I try and convert it to a `float` I end up with more than 2 decimal places.

What needs to happen, if possible, to get a result like the following?

```
{ 'sum': 500.50 }
```

Comment: I don't know much about django, but if you need two decimal places always and it's not possible to do exactly what you want you could multiply by 100 and work with it as an integer.

Comment: JSON is only defined to have double-precision floats for numbers. What does it buy you to keep your numbers as Decimals?

Comment: I don't need my numbers to be Decimal, they will never be that large. That's just what I get back from the DB as they are monetary values. I wasn't thrilled about using the int * 100 and floats give me more than two decimal places. I was just hoping there would be a more elegant solution...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you can do is extend the JSONDecoder class to provide a custom serializer for the Decimal type, similar to the example in this document: http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/json.html

```
>>> import json
>>> class DecimalEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
...     def default(self, obj):
...         if isinstance(obj, Decimal):
...             return "%.2f" % obj
...         return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
...
```

That's a nonworking example of how to do it, hopefully a good starting point for you.

Comment: Thanks, I like this solution the best so far :)

Comment: Actually Django provides a built-in class for exactly this - `django.core.serializers.json.DjangoJSONEncoder` - which you can use directly by doing `simplejson.dumps(mydict, class=DjangoJSONEncoder)`. It also deals with datetimes.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks. 'class=DjangoJSONEncoder' needed to be 'cls=DjangoJSONEncoder'. This does work, but it gives me a string value :(

Comment: hehe this gives me just a string value the same as just doing 'str(amount)' in the json.dumps calls... I've decided to just leave it as a string and handle it on the client..

Comment: You can make it whatever you want, just change the `return "%.2f" % obj` line.

Answer (score 0):

From this link : http://code.google.com/p/simplejson/issues/detail?id=34.

i can tell you tree think :

- use cjson it work fine with decimal values.
- use monkey patching like the example from this link: http://code.google.com/p/simplejson/issues/detail?id=61
- use jsonutil see the last comment : http://code.google.com/p/simplejson/issues/detail?id=34#c28

you can find more detail in the first link.

Answer (score 0):

Decimal can be cast to a float which javascript knows how to deal with

```
json.dumps( { 'sum': float(amount) } )
```

Comment: In my question I noted that I didn't want to pass down a float due to them having a large number of decimal places.

Answer (score -1):

There's no such thing as a Decimal type in Javascript, and also among the standard types in python. It is a database-spcific type and not part of JSON. Take Float or do an integer arithmetic.

Comment: Yes, I know there is no matching type in JavaScript, my values will never be that large. I simply want them to come down in a regular monetary format "5.95", but not in string format.

Comment: JSON standard is independent from JS. Also it defines numbers as sequence of digits with optional - and . not discussing the memory representation after parsing the number. Decimal is also standard in Python from 2.4, you have to import it explicitly thou (from decimal import Decimal). It's built-in nevertheless.