# Serialize models in django with proper decimal data types into json

Tags: python, django, serialization

Here is a sample model:

```
class FooModel(models.Model):
    foo = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=3, null=True)
```

Serialize:

```
from django.core import serializers
obj = get_object_or_404(FooModel, pk=1)
data = serializers.serialize("json", [obj])
```

That will return something like:

```
[
    {
        "pk": 1,
        "model": "app.foomodel",
        "fields": {
            "foo": "50"
        }
    }
]
```

**Question**

How can I make foo field to serialize as float, and not as string. I don't want to use float model type since float sometimes does not store decimals correctly.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the value actually `50` vs. `50.0`? A `Decimal` object maintains whatever was originally input, e.g. `Decimal('50')` yields `50`.

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> d = Decimal('50')
>>> print d
50
```

Unfortunately the arguments provided to the `DecimalField` constructor are only for restrictions on *storing* the values and not displaying them.

Now, because Django is just using the standard json/simplejson lib, you can specify a custom encoder when serializing, such as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4019897/194311):

```
import decimal
import json
class DecimalEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, decimal.Decimal):
            return '%.2f' % obj # Display Decimal obj as float
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

But it doesn't end there. As [detailed in this blog post](http://blog.adaptivesoftware.biz/2009/08/custom-json-encoder-in-django.html), Django is explicitly passing `cls=DjangoJSONEncoder` to `simplejson.dump(...)`, so we have to circumvent this by also creating a custom serializer object referencing the `DecimalEncoder` we created:

```
from django.core.serializers.json import Serializer as JSONSerializer
class DecimalSerializer(JSONSerializer):
    def end_serialization(self):
        self.options.pop('stream', None)
        self.options.pop('fields', None)
        json.dump(self.objects, self.stream, cls=DecimalEncoder, **self.options)
```

Next, you instantiate `DecimalSerializer` as your own serializer object, and magic happens:

```
my_serializer = DecimalSerializer()
print my_serializer.serialize([obj], indent=4)
```

Which yields:

```
[
    {
        "pk": 1, 
        "model": "app.foomodel", 
        "fields": {
            "foo": "50.00"
        }
    }
]
```

This seems like a lot of work. It might just be easier to use Django's [model validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) to make sure that a `FooModel.foo` field is always a floating point number, prior to saving.  Here is brute force attempt at that:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class FooModel(models.Model):
    foo = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=3, null=True)

    def clean(self):
        if '.' not in str(self.foo):
            raise ValidationError('Input must be float!')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.full_clean()
        super(FooModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

And then:

```
>>> f = FooModel(foo='1')
>>> f.save()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/jathan/sandbox/foo/app/models.py", line 15, in save
    self.full_clean()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 828, in full_clean
    raise ValidationError(errors)
ValidationError: {'__all__': [u'Input must be float!']}
```

Comment: This serialization still renders strings in the json.

Is there a reason not to replace " '.2f' % obj " with " float('.2f' % obj) "?

Comment: This is way too complicated -- probably better not to use Django's DecimalField in the first place.

Comment: You're probably right, but keep in mind this was posted 3.5 years ago in the days of Django 1.3. Please feel free to help me update it. :)